# Como inspecionar uma aplicação em Angular?

Tags: angular-6

Faz pouco tempo que entrei num projeto, eles utilizam Spring Boot com Angular. O modulo do projeto que fiquei responsável é o o modulo de movimentação pessoal como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A aplicação funciona da seguinte forma! O primeiro passo é clicar no botão editar como mostra com a seta abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida ele carrega essa tela como podem ver, em seguida o usuário precisa clicar no botão azul escuro como mostra na seta pra avançar os passos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

AQUI ABAIXO ESTÁ O PROBLEMA, observem para a onde a seta está apontando, não está carregando os dados do funcionário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu só preciso saber como poderei examinar porque não está carregando os dados do funcionário na tela.

Estou aberto a perguntas, preciso muito de ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, use o depurador do navegador.
No Firefox ou Chrome é só acionar a tecla F12 que abrirá o console

De uma lida nesse link, onde explica sobre:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/depurando-javascript-com-google-chrome/28367